# jQuery mobile popup not displaying when linked to from header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a webpage using jQuery mobile, part of my website includes a login feature and I am trying to show the login form in a popup on the page. The button linking to the popup is to be in the header of the page.

My problem is that the popup does not display when I click on the login button :/

I tried to remove the `ui-selectmenu-hidden` class from the `div` but that resulted in the popup being displayed without jQuery styles as soon as the page loads.

I know the code I have works without the `page` or `header` data-roles as I tested the exact code on another document without those `divs`.

Here is the code that's giving me the problem:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">Open Popup</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="b" class="ui-popup-container ui-selectmenu-hidden popups" data-overlay-theme="a">
    <form id="loginForm">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username..." />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Password..." />
        <input type="button" value="Login" data-theme="b" />
        <p>New to The Social Network?</p>
        <input type="button" value="Register here" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Any help here would be appreciated. It's likely I've made a silly mistake somewhere, but for the life of me I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the popup will only be accessed from this one page. Move the popup div inside the data-role="page" div at the same level as the header/content/footer.

If you want to access the login form from several pages, keep the markup as is, but add script on document ready to initialize the widget and enhance the content:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#popupLogin" ).enhanceWithin().popup();
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/j8cvhp68/)**